# Android reusable parts of UI with specific functionality

Tags: android-fragments, android

Is it possible to have a part of UI like a Fragment that has search functionality and be reusable? Meaning that I have the logic of the Fragment in one place and use it in other Activities without having to implement that logic in all of the Activities. I looked at Fragments and it seems that the logic is implemented in the Activity.

If not, is there a way to do this, or do i have to implement it in all Activities?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One of the great advantages of fragment is code reuse.

You can write all the search code on the fragment and load it from different activities. From the activity side you only have to set the fragment and handle logic specific to that view.